# DataDriver library methode _stats_suite failed : TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python-3.x, docker, robotframework

I am trying to launch my robot code on a docker image. So I have installed python 3 and all the libraries I need (I hope).
Here is an overview:

```
$ pip list
Package                        Version
------------------------------ -------
asn1crypto                     0.24.0 
bcrypt                         3.1.7  
cffi                           1.12.3 
configparser                   3.5.0b2
cryptography                   2.7    
cx-Oracle                      7.2.3  
entrypoints                    0.3    
enum34                         1.1.6  
ipaddress                      1.0.17 
keyring                        17.1.1 
keyrings.alt                   3.1.1  
mercurial                      4.8.2  
paramiko                       2.6.0  
pip                            18.1   
pycparser                      2.19   
pycrypto                       2.6.1  
PyGObject                      3.30.4 
PyNaCl                         1.3.0  
pyxdg                          0.25   
robotframework                 3.1.2  
robotframework-databaselibrary 1.2.4  
robotframework-datadriver      0.0.3  
robotframework-sshlibrary      3.3.0  
scp                            0.13.2 
SecretStorage                  2.3.1  
setuptools                     3.4    
six                            1.12.0 
wheel                          0.32.3
```

But when I try to launch the robot code, the first call it does in the code is towards the DataDriver library but it seems to fail.
From what I can find, the error would mean that it wasn't installed correctly but it is in the list as mentionned above.
Error I receive:

```
$ robot --outputdir output IPS/BCMC.robot
==============================================================================
BCMC                                                                          
==============================================================================
[ ERROR ] Calling method '_start_suite' of listener 'DataDriver' failed: TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
Dummy test Case                                                       | FAIL |
Test case contains no keywords.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BCMC                                                                  | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /builds/tcc--test-automation/back-office-bcmc/int2peach-bcmc/output/output.xml
Log:     /builds/tcc--test-automation/back-office-bcmc/int2peach-bcmc/output/log.html
Report:  /builds/tcc--test-automation/back-office-bcmc/int2peach-bcmc/output/report.html
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Here is the trace of the DataDriver module installation on the docker image:

```
$ pip install robotframework-datadriver==0.0.3
Collecting robotframework-datadriver==0.0.3
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5d/d2/d980c9fecca7bc595c1c86a9f8eaf67cc4c740b41317431c43cef2125c80/robotframework-datadriver-0.0.3.tar.gz (64kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: robotframework-datadriver
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for robotframework-datadriver: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for robotframework-datadriver: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/01/47/fe/ecf3f26ea74c3fd7a1089b0eb6ec41d232f36e17b315b3d7da
Successfully built robotframework-datadriver
Installing collected packages: robotframework-datadriver
Successfully installed robotframework-datadriver-0.0.3
```

Comment: There is a newer version available: 0.3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a mistake trying to match the library version I had on my own pc to the version installed on the image. Should have done it.
Removing the version specification in my pip installation fixed the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the encoding parameter when importing the library?

```
*** Settings ***    
Library    DataDriver
    ...    encoding=cp1252
```

Don't know which one is correct, but the below link has a link to other options.

The example is from [here](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-datadriver/).

Comment: I added the encoding but didn't change a thing. Still have the same error message.